# Can I run a LAMP server with a webmin interface on my raspberry pi on raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, script, bash

I would like to run a LAMP server with a webmin interface on my raspberry pi.

I am running the latest Raspbian but am having trouble getting Webmin. I tried the obvious...

```
sudo apt-get install webmin
```

..but it did not appear to find a package.

I see that sourceforge has a .deb package up here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/webadmin/files/webmin/1.720/

Can I install webmin on the Pi from the .deb package? And can I do it from the command line and completely from the Pi from SSH?

I would like it to be easy to install this entire LAMP / webmin setup on a fresh Raspberry Pi at will, as I like to experiment a lot. So, how can I write a bash shell script to automatically install the LAMP stack and webmin into a functional state? What is required?

With some additional research, I was able to answer my own question and have posted my finding below. Hope it helps some of you too.

Comment: You MUST ensure that deb packages you find on the www are compatible with the system running on your Pi.  Generally that means if you are using Raspbian you should only download binaries from the Raspbian repository.  Generally binaries you find on the www will be incompatible and you'll need to build from source.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone was interested, I've now been able to make an install script that worked on my current vanilla Raspbian install. Plus, ascii art!:

```
echo $"
        _________
       d         b
      d           b
     d             b
    d               b
   d                 b
    ''':::.....:::'''
           fff
         .'   '.
        ^       ^.'--.
        b       d     ,
         czzzzzd       ..oOo

LAMP (Top-of-Stack) Installer by Circuit
"
sudo groupadd -f -g33 www-data
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
sudo apt-get -y install phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get -y install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python libapt-pkg-perl
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/webadmin/webmin/1.720/webmin_1.720_all.deb
sudo dpkg --install webmin_1.720_all.deb
```

Then I can access the interface by going to any web browser on my wifi network and typing:

```
https://raspberrypi.local:10000
```

Then log in with the default raspberry pi credentials (or whatever you changed them to):

```
user: pi 
password: raspberry
```

Enjoy webmin awesomeness! Be warned, it eats up a fair amount of CPU cycles when you access various pages in webmin :)